# Why can't I change the value of a variable captured by copy in a lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm reading the C++ Programming Language by B. Stroustrup in its section 11.4.3.4 "mutable Lambdas", which says the following:

> Usually, we don’t want to modify the state of the function object (the
>   closure), so by default we can’t. That is, the `operator()()` for the
>   generated function object (§11.4.1) is a `const` member function. **In the
>   unlikely event that we want to modify the state (as opposed to
>   modifying the state of some variable captured by reference; §11.4.3),
>   we can declare the lambda mutable**.

I don't understand why the default for the `operator()()` is `const` when the variable is captured by value. What's the rational for this? What could go wrong when I change the value of a variable, which is **copied** into the function object?

Comment: It says right there in the first sentence: "Usually, we don’t want to modify the state of the function object (the closure), so by default we can’t."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One can think of lambdas as classes with `operator()()`, which by default is defined as `const`. That is, it cannot change the state of the object. Consequently, the lambda will behave as a regular function and produce the same result every time it is called. If instead, we declare the lambda as mutable, it is possible for the lambda to modify the internal state of the object, and provide a different result for different calls depending on that state. This is not very intuitive and therefore discouraged.

For example, with mutable lambda, this can happen:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  auto lam = [=]() mutable {
    n += 1;
    return n;
  };

  std::cout << lam() << "\n";  // Prints 1
  std::cout << n << "\n";      // Prints 0
  std::cout << lam() << "\n";  // Prints 2
  std::cout << n << "\n";      // Prints 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could give an example showing that the lambda will not produce the same result, once I change its state, using a variable passed by value to the lambda expression?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: The example was clear enough for me (+1). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to reason about const data.

By defaulting const, brief lamndas are easier to reason about.  If you want mutability you can ask for it.

Many function objects in std are copied around; const objects that are copied have simpler state to track.